# Using sed to replace string in file by using regex capture group

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I start by saying I am very new on shell script so please don't shoot me !! :)

I have a file that contains the following text:

```
1   :    / 
2   :    /string-1/ 
4   :    /string-2/ 
5   :    /string-3/
```

and I like to remove the end slashes of the strings so the result should be like that :

```
1   :    / 
2   :    string-1 
4   :    string-2 
5   :    string-3
```

I have try that by using the `sed` as following:

```
local_export_folder="/home/merianos/Documents/repositories/DatabaseBackup/tmp"

sed -i -e 's/\/([^\/]+)\//\1/' ${local_export_folder}/blogs.csv
```

but this doesn't work.

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Your title is misleading, there are no 'regular expression variables' here. Can you be more specific than 'this doesn't work'?

Comment: What I try to describe be the title is how to use the content of the parentheses as the replacement text. I don't know how to write that title better.

Comment: The part between the parentheses is called a _capture group_. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks !! :) That's really help's ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
sed 's#/\([^/]*\)/#\1#' file
```

This captures any content between two forward slashes. The replacement is the content, without the slashes.

One issue that you may have been facing is that `+` (one or more) isn't understood by all versions of sed. I have changed it to a `*` (which means zero or more), which is more widely recognised. If you prefer, you could use the POSIX-compliant `\{1,\}` to mean *one or more* instead.

Output:

```
$ sed 's#/\([^/]*\)/#\1#' file
1   :    /
2   :    string-1
4   :    string-2
5   :    string-3
```

Depending on your version of sed, you may be able to use the `-r` or `-E` switch to enable extended regular expressions. This means that parentheses don't need escaping to be used as capturing groups and the `+` is understood:

```
sed -r 's#/([^/]+)/#\1#' file
```

Comment: Thanks, while I used my regex, finally you helped me a lot, because I see that you escape the capture group parentheses too. So, when I escaped the parenthesis worked for me too.

Comment: And in case this is helpful, to destructively change the input, use: sed -i 's#/\([^/]*\)/#\1#' file

Comment: @Merianos I have mentioned a way of using the parentheses without having to escape them.